# SQL / PLSQL script to convert values in a database table as unique

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a (oracle) database table with column called name `VARCHAR`. I need to update the table to add a unique constraint on this column. But before I can add the unique constraint I need to ensure that all the values in the column are unique. I want to achieve this by adding suffixes like `-1`, `-2`, etc in case of duplicate entries.

For example if there are 3 rows having duplicate values in the name column, let's say the value is `Hari`, I want to change the values as `Hari`, `Hari-1`, `Hari-2`.

How can I achieve this using SQL / PLSQL only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MERGE` statement and the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID AS rid,
         name,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY name ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.rid )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET name = CASE rn
                    WHEN 1
                    THEN src.name
                    ELSE src.name || '-' || (rn - 1)
                    END;
```

Then use:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT table_name__name__u UNIQUE( name );
```

To create a named unique constraint on the column.

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( name ) AS
  SELECT 'Hari'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Hari'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Hari'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Alice'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Charlie' FROM DUAL;
```

**Output**:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

> ```
> | NAME    |
> | :------ |
> | Hari    |
> | Hari-1  |
> | Hari-2  |
> | Alice   |
> | Bob     |
> | Bob-1   |
> | Charlie |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cf69beb2fc6243b639fb6a1b949a00dd)*

Comment: Like this solution the most. Thanks much.

Comment: @Rahul Comments are ephemeral and can be deleted; instead you can upvote any (or all) helpful solutions using the arrows to the left of the question and, if an answer has solved your issue then you can click the check-mark below the voting buttons to mark it as your preferred answer and that will let other users know that you have a solution and are not looking for new answers (although they could still give them if they want).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest just using `ROW_NUMBER()` here to generate the identifier you want:

```
SELECT
    name,
    TO_CHAR(name || '-' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id)) AS name_new
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY name;
```

### Demo

Comment: This will add a number to **all** records, not only the duplicated ones. I would suggest `name || LTRIM('-0' FROM '-'||to_char(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id)-1))`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I was aware of this when I posted, and see the MT0 answer for a workaround.  Practically speaking, the value in what the OP is suggesting is in being able to distinguish one "duplicate" from another.  The answer I gave certainly does that, although it does place a number even against the "original" data point.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the example that @Tim Biegeleisen provided and adjusted his answer to get you the result you are asking for.

```
SELECT
    name,
    TO_CHAR(name ||
    case 
        when ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) = 1 then ''
        else to_char ('-' ||  (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id)-1)) 
    end) name_new
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY name;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8d8a1b3f5146b018f92a4c344ed40414